# how to format time in django-rest-framework's serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

there is my serializer code:
**serializer.py**

```
class StartListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializer.CharField()
    time = serializers.DateField(fromat=None, input_formats=None)
```

it will give me this:
`'time': '2014-03-14T22:44:16.923000'`
the input time format is `datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 14, 22, 44, 37, 280000)`
But I want to get time like this `2014-03-14 22:44:37`
how can I change my serializer to get this time?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The usual Python datetime format will work:

```
# for DateField
date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")

# for DateTimeField
time = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: can you help about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129830/how-can-i-add-field-in-serializer

Comment: This answer gives error for DateTime fields. Check @Flippym answer bellow.

Comment: The format may have changed in recent versions. I have `serializers.DateField(format='YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Answer (score 12):

After testing the accepted answer, I got the following error:

> AssertionError: Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, as this may mean losing timezone information. Use a custom read-only field and deal with timezone issues explicitly.

Using the serializer field as `datetime` solved the issue.

```
class StartListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    # ...
    time = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```