# how can I add field in serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Below is my `serializer.py` file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class TaskListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    user_id = serializers.CharField()
    status = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

In Python shell, I input this:

```
>>> from serializer import TaskListSerializer as ts

>>> result = ts({'id':1, 'user_id': 1, 'status':2, 'name': 'bob'})

>>> result.data

{'status': u'2', 'user_id': u'1', 'id': u'1', 'name': u'bob'}
```

Now I want do this:

First, the input is not change, is also `{'id':1, 'user_id': 1, 'status':2, 'name': 'bob'}`

But I want to add a `field` and change `name: bob` to `jim` in `serializer.py` and make output like this:

`{'status': u'2', 'user_id': u'1', 'id': u'1', 'name': u'jim', u'age': '15'}`

How can I do it in `serializer.py`?

Comment: Why not add a new field to the `TaskListSerializer` class?

Comment: in fact, I will do many complex thing,  in that I can't do this like you tall

Comment: then you want to add fields in your serializer but not in your serializer class? Do you think that is very clean?

Answer (score 0):

Use serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class TaskListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
complex_things = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_complex_things(self, obj):
        result_of_complex_things = 2 + 2
        return result_of_complex_things
```