# How to format datetime in a serialized model Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, django-models, datetime-format

I have the following model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    firstDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    another = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I serialize it to JSON with

```
 query = MyModel.objects.all()
 data = serializers.serialize('json', query, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

The DateTimeField returns the following format:

```
2017-12-19T22:50:04.328Z
```

The desired format is:

```
2017-12-19 22:50:04
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using the queryset.values() and queryset.extra() methods?

Comment: you can in the frontend to do that.

Comment: May be this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129563/how-to-format-time-in-django-rest-frameworks-serializer

Comment: Where is `serializers` coming from (what's the import statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by aircraft, I treat it in the front-end with the JavaScript built-in Date implementation (didn't know about it until now). It's perfect for manipulating formats and locales.

In specific, I used this object function: [Date.prototype.toLocaleFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create your own subclass of [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder) - which is a subclass of Python's standard JSON encoder that implements (among other things) the functionality that you wish to change.:

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/core/serializers/json.py), it's pretty trivial. You'll want to change the section starting with:

```
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
```

to have the method return the datetime in the format you desire.

```
class MyJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):        
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            # Your implementation here
        return super().default(o)
```