# Specify AM and PM TimeField in Django model and serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have my models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    opening_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)
    closing_time = models.TimeField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def is_open(self):
        return True if self.opening_time <= datetime.now().time() < self.closing_time else False
```

And, my serializer.py:

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'opening_time', 'closing_time')
```

How can I have so the time I input is either 24 hours or AM and PM.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to format time in django-rest-framework's serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129563/how-to-format-time-in-django-rest-frameworks-serializer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `settings.py` edit date time format

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%b %d at %I:%M %P"
}
```