# How to serialize DateTimeField in Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

#### How can I serialize dob field to achieve dob to be specifically in the format e.g ==> **03/Jan/2020 or 05-Feb-2021**

```
class PersonSerializer():
    ....
    ........
    dob = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d/%m/%Y")


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
```

What I have so far is in the format e.g 20/12/2020

Comment: You can also have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129563/how-to-format-time-in-django-rest-frameworks-serializer/34129862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DRF docs;

> DateTimeField format strings. Format strings may either be Python
> strftime formats which explicitly specify the format, or the special
> string 'iso-8601', which indicates that ISO 8601 style datetimes
> should be used. (eg '2013-01-29T12:34:56.000000Z')

So you can format it like `datetime.datetime` object. Such as

```py
class PersonSerializer():
    ....
    ........
    dob = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d/%b/%Y")

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
```

Also we have to mention that setting to a format string means that to_representation return values should be forced to string output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output dates in certain format globally then you set it in `settings.py` file.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_FORMAT': "%d/%m/%Y",
    #-- other settings-----#

}
```

However if you want to output for a certain field of model only then you can do this.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ....
    # ........
    custom_dob = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
```

You can create property in `Person` model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    dob = models.DateField()

    @property
    def custom_dob(self):
        return self.dob.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: This has already been achieved. See the format I suggested in the question

Comment: @7guyo Sorry i missed that,. But this is a general answer to format datetime fields globally and for specific fields. You can use the format that you want to output to.